# What is the difference between the Descendant combinator and the subsequent sibling combinator?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

To my knowledge,

the ***descendant combinator (space)*** targets child and descendants of the parent element.

the ***subsequent sibling combinator (~)*** selects all elements that come anywhere after a specified element whether its adjacent or not.

So with that definition wouldn't *`H1 p`* and *`H1 ~ p`* give me the same selection results every time?

The fact that both of these are even a thing, tells me that they have their purpose... So what am I missing?

**EDIT**** Correct me if I'm wrong - but after further research, I think I got it.

The (~) selects all elements that come ***AFTER*** a specified element. While the (space) selects all elements that are ***INSIDE*** of a specified element?

Comment: I recommend the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators) for your learning needs.

Answer (score -1):

> So with that definition wouldn't H1 p and H1 ~ p give me the same
> selection results every time?

Ans: Totally Wrong ...

> The (~) selects all elements that come AFTER a specified element.
> While the (space) selects all elements that are INSIDE of a specified
> element?

Ans: Yep, this one is correct.

**To Clarify:**

**Space_Selector: Selects all the elements inside the selector.**

```css
div p {background: red;}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1.</p>
<p>paragraph 2.</p>
<p>paragraph 3.</p>
<div>
  <p>paragraph 4.</p>
  <p>paragraph 5.</p>
  <p>paragraph 6.</p>
</div>
<p>paragraph 7.</p>
<p>paragraph 8.</p>
<p>paragraph 9.</p>
```

**Tilde/Sibling Selector (selects all coming/later siblings):**

```css
div ~ p { background: yellow;}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1.</p>
<p>paragraph 2.</p>
<p>paragraph 3.</p>
<div>
  <p>paragraph 4.</p>
  <p>paragraph 5.</p>
  <p>paragraph 6.</p>
</div>
<p>paragraph 7.</p>
<p>paragraph 8.</p>
<p>paragraph 9.</p>
```